# Gate not allows user while he has already that permission

Tags: php, laravel, authorization, laravel-8, laravel-gate

I'm working with Laravel 8.5 and I wanted to develop my own ACL.

So I made this **ManyToMany** relationship between Permission & User models:

**User.php:**

```
public function permissions()
    {
        return $this->belongsToMany(Permission::class);
    }
```

**Permission.php:**

```
public function users()
    {
        return $this->belongsToMany(User::class);
    }
```

Then I have inserted this custom permission into `permissions` table:

[image]

And then inserted this also into the pivot table `pemrission_user`:

[image]

Then at `web.php`, I tried this:

```
Route::get('/', function () {
    $user = auth()->user();
    // dd($user->permissions()->get());
    if(Gate::allows('edit-user')){
        dd(2);
    }else{
        dd(1);
    }
});
```

So I tried checking if the logged in user has the permission `edit-user`, then shows **2** as result but now it returns **1** somehow, meaning that user has not this permission!

However if I uncomment `dd($user->permissions()->get());`, I can see this:

[image]

So as it shows user already has this `edit-user` permission but I don't why the Gate does not authorize user in this case.

So if you know, I beg you to help me cause I really don't know how to solve this...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to define `edit-user` for your Gate as well because your permission model means nothing to the Gate at the moment.

```php
Gate::define('edit-user', function (User $user) {
    return $user->permissions()->whereName('edit-user')->exists();
});
```

More information can be found here: https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/authorization#writing-gates

---

Otherwise, you can use policies:

```
class UserPolicy
{
    public function update(User $user)
    {
        return $user->permissions()->whereName('edit-user')->exists();
    }
}
```

And then to allow the user:

```php
$user->can('update', User::make());
```

More information about policies can be found here: https://laravel.com/docs/master/authorization#creating-policies

---

There's also an open source package called [laravel-permission](https://github.com/spatie/laravel-permission) made by Spatie that you can have a look at to learn more.